# Unexpected decorator/generator behavior

Tags: python, generator, python-decorators

I created a timer decorator but it doesn't work if the decorated function is a generator.

```
import numpy as np
from time import time
from collections import Counter


def timer(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time()
        try:
            res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            end = time()
            timer.counter.update({f'{f.__module__}.{f.__name__}': end - start})
            raise e
        end = time()
        timer.counter.update({f'{f.__module__}.{f.__name__}': end - start})
        return res
    return inner
timer.counter = Counter()


class AA:
    @timer
    def __init__(self):
        a = np.array(range(1_000_000))

    @timer
    def __iter__(self):
        a = np.array(range(1_000_000))
        yield 'a'

    @timer
    def normal_fun(self):
        a = np.array(range(1_000_000))

    @timer
    def fun_with_yield(self):
        a = np.array(range(1_000_000))
        yield 'a'


a = AA()
for i in a:
    pass
a.normal_fun()
a.fun_with_yield()
print(timer.counter)
```

Output:

> Counter({'**main**.**init**': 0.10380005836486816, '**main**.normal_fun': 0.10372400283813477, '**main**.**iter**': 0.0, '**main**.fun_with_yield': 0.0})

Why is the generator functions' time equal 0.0 and how can I fix it?

Comment: Calling a generator function does not actually execute any of the code inside it - it just creates an iterator object, which could easily take less time than `time.time()` can register.  You have to iterate over the returned object for anything to happen.

Comment: Could you please post the output of `print(time.get_clock_info('time').resolution)`?

Comment: Thank you. I was suspecting that was the case. So to solve this problem I have to check `f` type and if it's a generator use yield instead of return and count each iteration separately, correct? Or is there a better way? Just to be clear I don't want to measure time spent inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I achieved expected results by creating another decorator for generators. The decorator is a generator in itself and counts time spent in each iteration.

```
def generator_timer(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time()
        try:
            res = f(*args, **kwargs)
            for i in res:
                end = time()
                timer.counter.update({f'{f.__module__}.{f.__name__}': end - start})
                yield i
                start = time()
        except Exception as e:
            end = time()
            timer.counter.update({f'{f.__module__}.{f.__name__}': end - start})
            raise e
        end = time()
        timer.counter.update({f'{f.__module__}.{f.__name__}': end - start})
    return inner


class AA:
    @timer
    def __init__(self):
        a = np.array(range(10_000_000))

    @generator_timer
    def __iter__(self):
        a = np.array(range(10_000_000))
        yield 'a'
        yield 'b'

    @timer
    def normal_fun(self):
        a = np.array(range(10_000_000))

    @generator_timer
    def fun_with_yield(self):
        a = np.array(range(10_000_000))
        yield a
```

> Counter({'**main**.**init**': 1.0399727821350098, '**main**.**iter**': 1.0183088779449463, '**main**.fun_with_yield': 1.0168907642364502, '**main**.normal_fun': 1.0156745910644531})